# Census.gov TIGER down, suggestions?

Tags: qgis, tiger

Census.gov is down for now.   I have a friend who is a teaching a GIS class in the San Francisco bay area and only has so many datasets downloaded for specific projects.  Does anyone have a large copy of this area or know of any mirror that the data could be downloaded from?  The class is using QGIS and is going to stall or have to start using data from another source for now to continue.  Any suggestions on other data sets to explore?

Comment: Tiger 2000 is available on http://arcdata.esri.com/data/tiger2000/tiger_download.cfm

Comment: This is the only link that has worked and has its own copy of census 2000 data:http://arcdata.esri.com/data/tiger2000/tiger_download.cfm

Answer (score 5):

[NHGIS](https://www.nhgis.org/documentation) has historical and modern census data, American Community Survey and GIS boundary files. It requires a (free) account to download data.

Answer (score 3):

Try [this bulk download site](http://census.ire.org/data/bulkdata.html). This site is up as of 10PM MST on 10/6.
From the website's home page:

> Investigative Reporters and Editors is pleased to announce the next phase in our ongoing Census project, designed to provide journalists with a simpler way to access 2010 Census data so they can spend less time importing and managing the data and more time exploring and reporting the data. The project is the result of work by journalists from the The Chicago Tribune, The New York Times, USA Today, CNN, the Spokesman-Review (Spokane, Wash.) and the University of Nebraska-Lincoln, funded through generous support from the Donald W. Reynolds Journalism Institute at the Missouri School of Journalism.

Thus, it is clear this is 2010 data only.

Comment: This site links back to census.gov so it doesn't work.  Can anyone with a rep move this answer down, it's clearly not an answer to my question.  I need something that doesn't run by pulling data off the census.gov servers.

Answer (score 1):

[MapCruizin.com](http://www.mapcruzin.com/download-free-arcgis-shapefiles.htm)

[CloudMade](http://downloads.cloudmade.com/)

How about ArcGISonline and you can search gis data there ?

Comment: http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2013/10/04/beyond-shutdown-us-government-data-on-arcgis-online/